# Using Igraph on multiple cores

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, parallel-processing, igraph

I am trying to combine two CSV files together in a graph_from_data_frame using multiple cores.

I already have the code developed (see below), I just need to adapt it to use more than one core.

The two csv file examples are posted below. Due to the volume of data in the csv's multiple cores are needed.

```css
id
123
321
231
423
353
534
345
646
346

from to weight
123  456 2
123  435 3
432  654 2
342  543 4
234  323 3
432  543 4
234  543 1
234  654 1

 edges <- read.csv("/Users/holly/edgeR.csv", header=T, as.is=T)
          nodes <- read.csv("/Users/holly/nodeR.csv", header=T, as.is=T)
  
#libraries 
library(igraph)
library(tictoc)
library(network)
library(data.table)
          
  #Edges data set includes from and to addresses for block 200k from Neo4j
  #edges <- read.csv("/Users/jonathanbailey/edges.csv", header=T, as.is=T)
  #Node data s                                                                                                                                                 et contains all the address nodes ids for block 200k
  #nodes <- read.csv("/Users/jonathanbailey/nodes.csv", header=T, as.is=T)

      #Show titles of data set
      head(nodes)                   
      head(edges)

        #Remove the weights column 
        #edges$weights <- NULL
          #Removes duplicate values in the nodes data set
          nodes <- nodes[!duplicated(nodes$id),] 
  
# persuades the data into a two-column matrix format for igraph 
el=as.matrix(edges) 
el[,1]=as.character(el[,1])
el[,2]=as.character(el[,2])
  
  #Creates a graph in R with edges and nodes
  clustergraph1 <- graph_from_data_frame(el, directed = FALSE, vertices = nodes)
    #Assigns the louvain algoritm to the above graph
    Community200k <- cluster_louvain(clustergraph1)
```

Is there a way to make the two csv files merge into the graph data frame using parallel cores?